# Quick and Easiest way to shift the string value?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a easy and quick way to shift the value as per my requirement in JavaScript. example

i have a value as `"12/31/2014"` i need a way to shift any value in to any of the index. how can i do with easy way. at present as a sample i like to shift the value like this: `"2014/12/31"` any one help me to achieve with easy way?

```
function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `userDate.split('/').reverse().join('')`

Comment: String manipulation is too complicated for your purpose. You can just use the Date() constructor. For example, to get the month of your string, simply type ``new Date("...").getMonth()``. Construct a new string by using the methods of the Date constructor.

Comment: it wont work. i need to shift the month after date

Comment: @Tracer69 - I am looking for a way to handle not only for this date. as a general to handle those kind of requirements.

Comment: I think you accidentally switched accounts.

Comment: Then use something like ``const [day, month, year] = userDate.split("/")`` and construct a new string from that.

Answer (score -1):

It works better for me: @thanks to Tracer69

```
function formatDate(userDate) {
 const [day, month, year] = userDate.split("/");
 return `${year}/${day}/${month}` ;
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```